# Fetch latest valid mysql tag from docker hub using jq

Tags: mysql, docker, shell, jq, dockerhub

I am using following command to fetch all release tags from mysql on docker hub :

```
wget -q https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/mysql/tags -O - | jq -r .[].name
```

Output is:

```
5.7.38
5.7.38-debian
5.7.38-oracle
5.7.4
5.7.4-m14
5.7.5
5.7.5-m15
5.7.6
5.7.6-m16
5.7.7
5.7.7-rc
5.7.8
5.7.8-rc
5.7.9
8
8-debian
8-oracle
8.0
8.0-debian
8.0-oracle
8.0.0
8.0.1
8.0.11
8.0.12
8.0.13
8.0.14
8.0.15
8.0.16
8.0.17
8.0.18
8.0.19
8.0.2
8.0.20
8.0.21
8.0.22
8.0.23
8.0.24
8.0.25
8.0.26
8.0.27
8.0.28
8.0.28-debian
8.0.28-oracle
8.0.29
8.0.29-debian
8.0.29-oracle
8.0.3
8.0.4
8.0.4-rc
debian
oracle
```

Is there a way i can fetch the latest stable version only? For example , i want to fetch 8.0.29 as it is the latest stable version for 8x version . And next time when 8.0.30 comes i get the output from the same command?

Can anybody please help or point me to right direction? I tried using xidel but could not find solution

Answer (score 1):

Extract any sequence of digits using `scan("\\d+")`, convert the strings to numbers using `tonumber`, and use that as argument for `sort_by` on the initial array, from which you can then output the last item using index `-1`.

```bash
jq -r 'map(.name) | sort_by(scan("\\d+") | tonumber)[-1]'
```

```json
8.0.29-oracle
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/TtKR-azf88A)

---

If for the output you only want the pure version number (`8.0.29` instead of `8.0.29-oracle`), ditch everything after and including the dash sign:

```bash
jq -r 'map(.name | .[:index("-")]) | sort_by(scan("\\d+") | tonumber)[-1]'
```

```json
8.0.29
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/J0pgBivUwpM)

Answer (score 1):

> *I tried using xidel but could not find solution*

If you're still interested, it's not that hard:

```
$ xidel -s "https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/mysql/tags" -e '
  (
    for $x in $json()/name[matches(.,"^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$")]
    order by $x
    return $x
  )[last()]
'
8.0.29
```

- `[matches(.,"^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$")]` returns only those `name`s with just digits.
- `order by $x` for sorting.
- `(`...`)[last()]` to return the last item of the sequence (in this case the latest version).

Alternatively and even shorter, you can use `max()`:

```
$ xidel -s "https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/mysql/tags" -e '
  max($json()/name[matches(.,"^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$")])
'
8.0.29
```

Comment: I tried the same logic with postgres image. I am getting output as 9.6.24 even tough 14x version is available. Does this regex only handle versions starting with single digit? I am sorry i am not good with regex and still learning . I used this command for postgres :  xidel -s "https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/postgres/tags" -e ' max($json()/name[matches(.,"^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$")]) '

Comment: The regex accepts, and **only** accepts, strings with the pattern `x.x.x`, where `x` means "1 or more digits" (what `\d+` implies). If you want to accept `x.x` and `x` as well, then I believe `"^\d+\.?\d*\.?\d*$"` should do.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version has the `latest` tag. "stable" is in the eye of the beholder and not computable with the given information.